# With C# winforms, can I create a button that begins edit of a selected cell in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms app form with a datagridview

I know I can double click in a cell to edit it but I want a user of my program to be able to be able to have a button to begin edit of a/the selected cell in the datagridview (without having to move the mouse to it and double click it)

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't forget to educate the users that they also should be able to press F2, (which usually will be simpler that going to a button ;-)

Comment: @TaW thats a nice hint.. this highly increases the useability

Comment: [See here for a list..](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/keys_general.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the user already selected a cell your button just need to active the edit with `BeginEdit` like so
[MSDN link to method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
dgvExample.BeginEdit(true);
```

> the parameter of the method is used to select the complete cells content
>   or not.

you might check if there is already a cell selected, if not maybe use a default cell (e.g. 0,0) to edit